# Why is the If statements inside the for loop not working except the first condition whichever it satisfies?

Tags: c

I want the code to execute the average marks of all students simultaneously and also determine the grade of the student after printing each average marks.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
        
int main()
{
    int stud_rlno[8], phy_marks[8], chem_marks[8], 
        bio_marks[8], CS_marks[8], average;
    int i;
    for(int i = 0; i < 1; ++i)
    {
        printf("Enter the roll number of student %d: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &stud_rlno[i]);
        printf("Enter the physics marks of student %d: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &phy_marks[i]);
        printf("Enter the chemistry marks of student %d: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &chem_marks[i]);
        printf("Enter the biology marks of student %d: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &bio_marks[i]);
        printf("Enter the CS marks of student %d: ", i);
        scanf("%d", &CS_marks[I]);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i <= 1; i++)
    {  
        average = phy_marks[i] + chem_marks[i] + bio_marks[i] + CS_marks[i];
        printf("The average of student is %d \n", average / 4);
            if(average > 90)
        {
            printf("Grade A \n");
        }   
        else if(average <= 90 && average > 82)
        {
            printf("Grade B \n");
        }
        else if(average <= 82 && average > 75)
        {
            printf("Grade C \n");
        }
        else if(average <= 75 && average > 65)
        {
            printf("Grade D \n");
        }
        else if(average <= 65)
        {
            printf("Grade E \n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Fail");
        }
    }
}
```

The if statements inside the for loop don't work, Why are the If statements inside the for loop not working except for the first condition whichever it satisfies? I tried with many variations but it still doesn't work.

Comment: The `<=` here `for(int i = 0; i <= 1; i++)` causes undefined behavior since you only read values into index 0 of the uninitialized arrays but the second loop will access index 0 and 1.  You divide the total by 4 when you print it but the variable `average` is still the total value when tested in the `if` statements. If both of those issues are corrected it seems fine to me: https://godbolt.org/z/4T7q8WTxd

Comment: `average` is the sum of all the marks, and not actually the average.  Is that the issue?

Comment: `int i;` is shadowed by each `for(int i = 0; i < 1; ++i)` which defeats the purpose of declaring `int i;` outside the loop in order to preserve its value. Next, since you fail to check the return of each `scanf("%d", ...)` you have no way of knowing if you have valid data and no elegant way to break the read loop after entering the number of students you desire. While `fgets()` is recommended for all user-input (because of the pitfalls associated with `scanf()`), you could have the user enter `'d'` or `"done"` when done entering the students and save the value of `i` from the first loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your for loop. While executing, your program will iterate for only once as you have selected condition to be `for (i=0; i<1;i++)`. I would advise you to take what will be the size of array (no.of students) and set the value of `i`.

secondly,

```
sum = phy_marks[i] + chem_marks[i] + bio_marks[i] + CS_marks[i];
average = sum/4;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your program calculates the average mark for a single student,(for i=0; i<1; i++). This means that it would still work without the loops. As shown below.
To use use a loop in calculating the average mark for each student, consider the second part of this answer.

```
int stud_rlno;
float phy_marks,chem_marks,bio_marks,CS_marks,average;
printf("Enter the roll number of student: ");
scanf("%d", &stud_rlno);
printf("Enter the physics marks of student %d: ",stud_rlno);
scanf("%f", &phy_marks);
printf("Enter the chemistry marks of student %d: ",stud_rlno);
scanf("%f", &chem_marks);
printf("Enter the biology marks of student %d: ",stud_rlno);
scanf("%f", &bio_marks);
printf("Enter the CS marks of student %d: ",stud_rlno);
scanf("%f", &CS_marks);
average=(phy_marks+chem_marks+bio_marks+CS_marks)/4;
printf("The average of student is %.2f.\n", average / 4);
if(average > 90){
    printf("Grade A \n");
}   
else if(average <= 90 && average > 82){
    printf("Grade B \n");
}
else if(average <= 82 && average > 75){
    printf("Grade C \n");
}
else if(average <= 75 && average > 65){
    printf("Grade D \n");
}
else if(average <= 65){
    printf("Grade E \n");
}
else{
    printf("Fail");
}
```

To calculate the average mark for a given number of students, consider the code below:
The program prompts the user to enter the number of students. It then prompts the user to enter marks for all the four subjects, for each student. simultaneously the program prints out the marks, calculates the average and prints out the average and the grade.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(){
    char *subject[]={"Physics","Chemistry","Biology","CS"};
    int no_of_students;
    printf("Enter the number of students: ");
    scanf("%d",&no_of_students);
    int i,j;
    float marks[100][4];
    //Marks input for all subjects ,for each students.
    for(i=0; i<no_of_students; i++){
        printf("For student %d enter: \n",i+1);
        for(j=0; j<4; j++){
            printf("%s marks: ",subject[j]);
            scanf("%f",&marks[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("Student\tPhysics\tChemistry\tBiology\tCS\n");
    float sum,average;
    for(i=0; i<no_of_students; i++){
        printf("%d\t",i+1);//lists the students.
        sum=0;
        for(j=0; j<4; j++){
            printf("%.2f\t",marks[i][j]);//prints the marks.
            sum+=marks[i][j];//Sums marks for individual student.
        }
        average=sum/4;//calculates the average per student.
        printf("%.2f\t",average);//prints the average.
        //Grades the average mark.
        if(average > 90){
        printf("Grade A \n");
        }   
        else if(average <= 90 && average > 82){
            printf("Grade B \n");
        }
        else if(average <= 82 && average > 75){
            printf("Grade C \n");
        }
        else if(average <= 75 && average > 65){
            printf("Grade D \n");
        }
        else if(average <= 65){
            printf("Grade E \n");
        }
        else{
            printf("Fail");
        }
    }

}
```